KDB convert file handle to regular path
I am getting a file path as an input. I am trying to load a .q file that exists in that location. Is there a way to undo hsym?
Handle:  `:/path/to/schemafile.q
Expected output: /path/to/schemaFile.q
I tried 'value' but that isn't working.
I am ultimately trying to save the contents of schemaFile.q in a variable
schemaTab: \l /path/to/schemaFile.q
Thanks!

Can you include an example of contents of schemafile.q? One table definition? On a single líne? Not being assigned to a variable?

schemaFIle.q is a standard .q file with schemas of multiple tables : table1: ([] time:time$(); sym: symbol$(); cusip: (); price: float$()); table2: ([] time: time$(); sym: symbol$(); market:symbol$()); I am looking to do a count tables[] once I load the contents

To remove the : from a hsym
`$1_ string Handle

But your description of what you want suggests maybe you want the q code as a string?
schemaTab:read0 Handle 

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/read0/
This syntax example you show will not work:
schemaTab: \l /path/to/schemaFile.q

Commands using \ must be at the start of lines only, and cannot be passed variables. To run them anywhere and pass variables use system:
Handle: `:/path/to/schemafile.q
system"l ",1_ string Handle

Checking how many additional tables were added:
Handle: `:/path/to/schemafile.q
tabs:count tables[]
system"l ",1_ string Handle
-1 "Loaded ",string[count[tables[]]-tabs]," tables";

More advanced again would be to use .z.vs:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zvs-value-set
q).z.vs:{[x;y] if[x in tables[];-1 "Defined table:", string x]}
q)\l schema.q
Defined table:table1
Defined table:table2

More advanced tracking:
q)existingTables:tables[]
q)newTables:`$()
q).z.vs:{[x;y] if[x in tables[];$[x in existingTables;-1 "Redefined table: ", string x;[-1 "Defined table: ", string x;newTables,:x]]]}
q)\l schema.q
Defined table: table1
Defined table: table2

q)newTables
`table1`table2
q)count newTables
2

//Running again but showing behaviour if tables get redefined
q)existingTables:tables[]
q)newTables:`$()

q)\l schema.q
Redefined table: table1
Redefined table: table2
q)count newTables
0

// Use \x to remove the custom handler when no longer needed
q)\x .z.vs


I want to count number of tables in schemaFile.q so reading as a text complicates this. If it is loaded like how TP/RTDB loads a schema file then that would be perfect. Only issue is that this loading needs to happen inside a function only if certain criteria is met. \l isn't working and I get 'nyi error.

Have added some more examples now that the goal is clearer.
